# in SuperCollider what is the best way to render a sound a file?

Tags: supercollider

What is the best way to programatically render a SuperCollider program to a file (say a *wav* file).

Can I specify the duration of the file (eg 30 seconds)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `Score.recordNRT`.

There's a tutorial on how to use it [here](http://supercollider.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/supercollider/trunk/common/build/Help/Other%20Topics/Non-Realtime-Synthesis.html).

Comment: Link is broken (project moved to GitHub). This should be the new URL: http://doc.sccode.org/Guides/Non-Realtime-Synthesis.html

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of different ways to do this in addition to `Score.recordNRT` (which is maybe one of the more convenient ones, and also something I did not know about). `DiskOut.ar` takes `path` and `channelsArray` as `args`. You could also try the `.record` instance method that `Server` has. Here are examples (from the help docs) of both:

The `DiskOut.ar` way

```
// start something to record
x = Synth.new("bubbles");

// allocate a disk i/o buffer
b= Buffer.alloc(s, 65536, 2);

// create an output file for this buffer, leave it open
b.write("~/diskouttest.aiff".standardizePath, "aiff", "int16", 0, 0, true);
// create the diskout node; making sure it comes after the source
d = Synth.tail(nil, "help-Diskout", ["bufnum", b]);
// stop recording
d.free;
// stop the bubbles
x.free;
// close the buffer and the soundfile
b.close;
// free the buffer
b.free;

// play it back
(
x = Synth.basicNew("help-Diskin-2chan");
m = { arg buf; x.addToHeadMsg(nil, [\bufnum,buf])};

b = Buffer.cueSoundFile(s,"~/diskouttest.aiff".standardizePath, 0, 2, completionMessage: m);
)
x.free; b.close; b.free; // cleanup
```

The `Server.record` way:

```
s.boot; // start the server

// something to record
(
SynthDef("bubbles", {
    var f, zout;
    f = LFSaw.kr(0.4, 0, 24, LFSaw.kr([8,7.23], 0, 3, 80)).midicps; // glissando function
    zout = CombN.ar(SinOsc.ar(f, 0, 0.04), 0.2, 0.2, 4); // echoing sine wave
    Out.ar(0, zout);
}).add;
SynthDef("tpulse", { arg out=0,freq=700,sawFreq=440.0;
    Out.ar(out, SyncSaw.ar(freq,  sawFreq,0.1) )
}).add;

)

x = Synth.new("bubbles");

s.prepareForRecord; // you have to call this first

s.record;

s.pauseRecording; // pausable

s.record // start again

s.stopRecording; // this closes the file and deallocates the buffer recording node, etc.

x.free; // stop the synths

// look in your recordings folder and you'll find a file named for this date and time
```